# Complex number forming equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose we have 3 complex numbers , such that $$|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$$ and they form equilateral triangle then will condition $$z_1.z_2.z_3=1$$ always be true? I know cube roots of unity , that is $w,w^2,1$ satisfy here but is this always true?

Comment: Why should the product be 1? Try with any complex number, say $2+i$.

Comment: @user45195 Its mod is not one.

Comment: @user45195 which number should be $2+i$?

Comment: I mean to say the condition needn't necessarily be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Rotate the three point by multiplying with $e^{i\theta}$. Then the product is multiplied by $e^{3i\theta}$.

Comment: Hmm so will they always satisfy z1 + z2 + z3 = 0 ??